# Conditional expectation of a vector

Tags: conditional-probability, conditional-expectation, random-vector

Suppose we have two random vectors $X=(X_1,X_2)^T$ and $Y=(Y_1,\dots,Y_n)^T$. I wish to find a simple definition or formula for

$$
E_{X|Y=y}[X]
$$

Intuitively, I think the following is correct:

$$
E_{X|Y=y}[X]=\begin{pmatrix}E_{X_1|Y=y}[X_1]\\E_{X_2|Y=y}[X_2]\end{pmatrix}
\tag{1}
$$

Is this right? I imagine another possible definition could be

$$
E_{X|Y=y}[X]=\begin{pmatrix}E_{X|Y=y}[X_1]\\E_{X|Y=y}[X_2]\end{pmatrix}
\tag{2}
$$

But I don't think (2) is correct. I say this because, in the case of discrete $X$, (3) is more intuitive to me than (4):

$$
\big[E_{X|Y=y}[X]\big]_1=\sum_{x_1}x_1p_{X_1|Y}(x_1|y)=\sum_{x_1}x_1P(X_1=x_1|Y=y)
\tag{3}
$$

$$
\big[E_{X|Y=y}[X]\big]_1=\sum_{x}x_1p_{X|Y}(x|y)=\sum_{x}x_1P(X=x|Y=y)
\tag{4}
$$

Comment: Why are some vectors row vectors and others column vectors?

Comment: Thank you, @DilipSarwate. I have fixed this. They're all column vectors now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(1) is correct and intuitive; while (2) is also correct because you can calculate $E[X_1]$ using the density of $X_1$ or the joint density of $X_1$ and $X_2$, e.g. (in your notation)

$$\begin{align}
E_{X|Y=y}[X_1] &= \sum_x{x_1P(X=x|Y=y)} \\
 &= \sum_{x_1}\sum_{x_2}{x_1P(X_1=x_1,X_2=x_2|Y=y)} \\
 &= \sum_{x_1}x_1\sum_{x_2}{P(X_1=x_1,X_2=x_2|Y=y)} \\
 &= \sum_{x_1}{x_1}P(X_1=x_1|Y=y) \\
 &= E_{X_1|Y=y}[X_1]
\end{align}$$